# React navigation 5 deep linking when using class components

Tags: react-navigation, deep-linking, react-navigation-v5

I'm looking for an example of using react navigation 5 with class components - specifically for deep link handling.

Since class components can't use hooks the example doc does not help much. My implementation is using getStateFromPath(..) followed by ...reset(..) This works great when app starts closed but with app open the navigation never happens at ...reset().

An example of how deep linking works with class components would be great.